# Update Array By ID

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
    $arrays = array(
        array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => '', 'cat_name' => 'Food & Beverage', 'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 25, 'image' => 'books_image/calories_fat_carbohydrate.png' ),

        array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => '', 'cat_name' => 'Food & Beverage', 'quantity' => 5, 
       'price' => 38, 'image' => 'books_image/the_law_relating_to_food.png' ),

        array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => '', 'cat_name' => 'Food & Beverage', 'quantity' => 5, 
       'price' => 19, 'image' => 'books_image/it_starts_with_food.png' ),

        array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => '', 'cat_name' => 'Food & Beverage', 'quantity' => 2,
        'price' => 19, 'image' => 'books_image/it_starts_with_food.png' )
    );
```

And my desired output is:

```
$arrays = array(
    array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => '', 'cat_name' => 'Food & Beverage', 'quantity' => 3,
    'price' => 25, 'image' => 'books_image/calories_fat_carbohydrate.png' ),

    array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => '', 'cat_name' => 'Food & Beverage', 'quantity' => 5, 
   'price' => 38, 'image' => 'books_image/the_law_relating_to_food.png' ),

    array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => '', 'cat_name' => 'Food & Beverage', 'quantity' => 5, 
   'price' => 19, 'image' => 'books_image/it_starts_with_food.png' ),

);
```

Basically when I find arrays with the same key ("ID") I want to add them to the quantity.
How can I do this easily in php? I have been stumbling upon this and have tried the following but its not working at all.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($arrays); $i++) {
    // if this is not the first loop and if this is a duplicate
    if(isset($temp_id) && $temp_id == $arrays[$i]['id']) {
        // add quantity of the previous array here
        $arrays[$i]['quantity'] += $temp_quantity;
        // unset previous array
        unset($arrays[$i-1]);
    }
    $temp_id = $arrays[$i]['id'];
    $temp_quantity = $arrays[$i]['quantity'];
}
```

Comment: the other fields are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) for this:

```
$result = array_values(array_reduce($arrays, function ($result, $entry) {
  if (isset($result[$entry['id']])) {
    $result[$entry['id']]['quantity'] += $entry['quantity'];
  }
  else {
    $result[$entry['id']] = $entry;
  }
  return $result;
}, []));
```

[Demo here](https://3v4l.org/iNDfb)